# How to calculate $\int_0^1e^{i \pi x}x^x(1-x)^{(1-x)}dx$=?

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to calculate the following integral
$$\int_0^1 e^{i \pi x}x^x(1-x)^{(1-x)} dx$$
I tried parts integration, but it became more complicated, using mathematica shows the result looks like a pure imaginary number.

Any help or hint will be Appreciated